# How to fix "OSError: cannot identify image file"? I am trying to get image size by passing the image url

Tags: python-requests, python-imaging-library, python-3.5, urllib, eoserror

I am passing url of an image to get its size (height and width) but it seems python is not able to fetch this url. I am using python 3.5

The actual code is:-

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from PIL import Image

url = 'https://zdnet3.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/r/2014/12/01/f7247ce5-7921-11e4-b569-d4ae52e95e57/thumbnail/70x53/a5599f31ffa560131f54bcf8442e80ba/zd-defaultimage-news.jpg'
img = Image.open(urlopen(url))

print("Image size:", img.size)
```

I got this error:

> "OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000002907E898308>"

Comment: The file you link to is compressed with `gzip`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Great find! How did you figure this out?

Comment: I downloaded the file, saved it as `a.jpg` and then ran `file a.jpg` and it said *"gzipped data"*.